# Ag-grid com Angular2 usando angular-cli

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou tentando rodar ag-grid com angular2, os exemplos que tem no site do ag-grid são utilizando SystemJS como builder, e o novo angular-cli usa webpack.

Abaixo vou colocar a forma como consegui rodar, mas da forma abaixo não estou usando o ag-grid-ng2. Pois não sei onde devo referenciar a biblioteca extra do ag-grid-ng2.

Queria usar algo como nesse passo-a-passo:
https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angular-2-data-grid/

Estou usando:

- Node: 6.9.2
- NPM: 4.0.5
- Typescript: 2.1.4
- Angular CLI: 1.0.0-beta.22-1
- Ag-Grid: 7.0.2

Usei os seguintes comandos para iniciar o projeto, e não alterei nada a não ser o que será descrito abaixo:

```
ng new MeuProjeto
cd MeuProjeto
npm install --save ag-grid
npm install --save ag-grid-ng2
```

Depois editei o arquivo 'angular-cli.json':

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
    "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-blue.css",
    "styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.js"
],
```

Arquivo: app.component.html

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>

<div  id="grid-teste"
      style="height: 250px;" 
      class="ag-blue">
</div>
```

Arquivo: app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Grid, GridOptions } from "ag-grid/main";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'app works!';
  gridOptions: GridOptions;

  constructor() {   
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
    this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [];
    this.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({ headerName: 'name', field: 'name' });

    var el = document.querySelector('#grid-teste');
    new Grid(<HTMLDivElement>el, this.gridOptions);

    let data: any[] = [];
    data.push({name: 'Nome 1'});
    data.push({name: 'Nome 2'});
    data.push({name: 'Nome 3'});
    this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
  }

}
```

Obrigado.